# I can't view the Classes implementation of Unity Project

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, implementation

I am working on a game using **Unity** and I need to write some scripts using `C#` and a `Playfab API`, and I need to view some classes' implementation to know how the objects work. I used to do that by clicking `Ctrl` and pressing on the Class name when I am in a different project than the **Unity** project, but it doesn't work with the **Unity** project.

I am using **VScode**.
When I use the above method with the **Unity** project it keeps giving a message that say

> No implementation found for "Class Name"

What can I do

Comment: What implementation are you looking for? Also, I'd switch to regular Visual Studio for Unity development, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: @MaxPlay I am looking for the Classes implementation of Playfab so I can read it to understand how it works.

Comment: @MaxPlay What does this have to do with my question, I am asking for how I can open the Classes Implementation not where I can find an implementation for the Playfab!

Comment: You literally wrote "I am looking for the Classes implementation of Playfab". Your VSCode doesn't seem to get it somehow, so I gave you the implementation.

Comment: @MaxPlay What I am trying to say is that I want the feature from the VScode to return working. Thank you for helping me with a temporary solution for the Playfab implementation. But I was asking for the VScode feature more than the Playfab Implementation it self.